# Reporting library for Qt and C++

Tags: c++, qt, reporting

I'm looking for a reporting library for C++. What I need to do in my project is to present some statistical reports (pdf files including some grids and charts) based on the historical data stored in the database. We are using Qt and C++. I've done some research about it and found some libraries. Especially NCReports and KD Reports look fine for my requirements but they are expensive for me to use since I'm about to cross the budget limit allocated for my project. Therefore free and open source libraries are preferable.

Any suggesstions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is late to say this but for the ones who are looking for this kind of library I can say that Chart Director is very simple, cheap and good.

Answer (score 1):

[exaro](http://code.google.com/p/exaro/) seem a good option. I have not tried it though.
It is also available on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/exaro).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [libHaru](http://libharu.org/wiki/Main_Page) . I had used it earlier with my MFC application and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is still looking for a C++ report library, there is a good project I've recently found: https://sourceforge.net/projects/qreport/

> CuteReport is a free report solution based on Qt4 framework and it can
>   be easily used with any Qt application. In general, CuteReport
>   consists of two parts: core library and template designer. Both are
>   totally modular and theirs functionality can be easily extended by
>   writing additional modules. It's totally abstract of used data and can
>   use as storage: file system, database, version control systems, etc.
>   The projects's goal is to provide powerful, but yet simple to use for
>   inexperienced user and report designers, reporting system.